# I trying to Copy non blank and non-merged cells with in a range and paste it in another summary sheet

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub SelectAllNonBlankCells()
    Dim objUsedRange As Range
    Dim objRange As Range
    Dim objNonblankRange As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set sh = Worksheets("Summary")  ' Summary Sheet
    sh.Range("A11:P1000").Clear

    Set objUsedRange = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("B4:B15")

    For Each objRange In objUsedRange
        If Not (objRange.Value = "" And objRange.MergeCells = True) Then
           If objNonblankRange Is Nothing Then
              Set objNonblankRange = objRange
           Else
              Set objNonblankRange = Application.Union(objNonblankRange, objRange)
           End If
        End If
    Next

    If Not (objNonblankRange Is Nothing) Then
       objNonblankRange.Copy
       sh.Range("B11").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: Referance cells to the code]

Comment: Don't just dump code, please ask a specific question and tell us what's wrong with your code.

Comment: What you try is clear, but which is your problem? Do you receive an error? The code doesn't do what you need?